# WP7 background service

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am a Winform/Webforms developer and relatively new to WP7. I am making an application and i am confused regarding the following.

My application will be installed on WP7 and it will communicate with a web service to get some data. The application needs to run in background so at specific time it can show some data to the user in the form of widget or notification. The user will only open the installed application to change the general settings only.

1- How to make widgets in WP7 ? does it support it ?

2- In android we can make a service that runs in the background. How can we do it here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WP7, you can use the [tile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to show your data, the tile is like the widgets in Android platform. Besides, you can use the [Push Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402537%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to show your data, it's like the notification in Android.

For Q2, you can use the [Background Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to make your service that runs in the background, for example, you can use th PeriodicTask to get your data throught the background webservice.

Comment: But you have lots of limitations. Periodic Task has only 15 seconds to run, and only 6 mb of memory to use. Also, it can we swiched of by user or by OS without any notification.

Comment: @AntonSizikov Actually,in order to save electricity, the Windows Phone Background Agents do have lots of limitations. So it's  a pity that you have to accept it.